# Groupby and find similar or same items in two columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a data frame as follows, if the string in `name2` is approximately similar or same as the string in `name1` in each group of `type`, then return `Y`, otherwise `N`.

```
   id type     name1      name2
0   1    A  James B.      James
1   2    A     Keras     Steven
2   3    A       NaN      Keras
3   4    B      Jack       Lucy
4   5    B      Lucy       Jack
5   6    C    Jasica     Hoverd
6   7    C    Steven     Jasica
7   8    C       NaN  Steven L.
```

The expected result is like this, for example, in `type` `A`, `James` from `name2` have a similar value `James B.` in `name1`, `Keras` has same values in both `name2` and `name1`, so both of them return `Y` in `result`. While `Steven` does not exist in `name1`, so return `N`.

```
   id type     name1      name2 result
0   1    A  James B.      James      Y
1   2    A     Keras     Steven      N
2   3    A       NaN      Keras      Y
3   4    B      Jack       Lucy      Y
4   5    B      Lucy       Jack      Y
5   6    C    Jasica     Hoverd      N
6   7    C    Steven     Jasica      Y
7   8    C       NaN  Steven L.      Y
```

Someone could help to do that? Thank you.

If find similar values is too complicated to realize, then find only same values and return `Y` will be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without similarity it is simplier:

```
mask = df.groupby('type', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x['name2'].isin(x['name1']))
df['new'] = np.where(mask, 'Y','N')
print (df)
   id type     name1      name2 new
0   1    A  James B.      James   N
1   2    A     Keras     Steven   N
2   3    A       NaN      Keras   Y
3   4    B      Jack       Lucy   Y
4   5    B      Lucy       Jack   Y
5   6    C    Jasica     Hoverd   N
6   7    C    Steven     Jasica   Y
7   8    C       NaN  Steven L.   N
```

With basic similarity with split:

```
mask = (df.assign(name1 = df['name1'].fillna('|').astype(str).str.split().str[0],
                  name2 = df['name2'].astype(str).str.split().str[0])
          .groupby('type', group_keys=False)
          .apply(lambda x: x['name2'].isin(x['name1'])))
df['new'] = np.where(mask, 'Y','N')
print (df)

   id type     name1      name2 new
0   1    A  James B.      James   Y
1   2    A     Keras     Steven   N
2   3    A       NaN      Keras   Y
3   4    B      Jack       Lucy   Y
4   5    B      Lucy       Jack   Y
5   6    C    Jasica     Hoverd   N
6   7    C    Steven     Jasica   Y
7   8    C       NaN  Steven L.   Y
```

For better matchin similarity is possible use `SequenceMatcher` for ratio and filter it by treshold, e.g. here by `0.5`:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def f(x):
    comp = [any(SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio() > .5 
                                   for a in x['name1'].fillna('_')) 
                                   for b in x['name2']]
    return pd.Series(comp, index=x.index)

mask = df.groupby('type', group_keys=False).apply(f)
df['new'] = np.where(mask, 'Y','N')
print (df)
   id type       name1      name2 new
0   1    A    James B.      James   Y
1   2    A       Keras     Steven   N
2   3    A         NaN      Keras   Y
3   4    B        Jack       Lucy   Y
4   5    B        Lucy       Jack   Y
5   6    C      Jasica     Hoverd   N
6   7    C  Steven LA.     Jasica   Y
7   8    C         NaN  Steven L.   Y
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't match his expected output

Comment: Thank you, but I got a same error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`.

Comment: @ahbon - I convert both NaNs to some different values like `|||` and `___` and then convert to strings, can you check now?

Comment: It works right now, thanks Jezrael. But I don't understand why convert `NaN`s to `|||` and `___`.

Comment: @ahbon - Problem is if casting to strings then match `nan`s with `nan`s, because strings `'nan' == 'nan'`. so for avoid matching there is necessary convert at least to to something else,

Comment: It seems iamklaus's solution doesn't convert `nan`s, but drop them, will that be OK?

Comment: yes, I suggest it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110784/groupby-and-find-similar-or-same-items-in-python/58110936#comment102612373_58111017). Btw, there is necessary only match by splitting by first values before space like `Steven L.` to `Steven` ? Or need mach like `Steven L.` to `Steven LA.` ?

Comment: @ahbon - Edited answer for another general solution with `SequenceMatcher`

Comment: Both cases are possible, if values in `name2` are same or similar to values in `name1` in each group of `type`, then return `Y`. Please note it is not necessary to split by `space`.

Comment: @ahbon - yes, so another answer is about split, also my second answer is about split, so cannot be used. Need last answer with the more general matching similarity, if necessary match like `Steven L. to Steven LA.` Or `Steven to Stevens`

Comment: Both your answer and imaklaus's are awsome, sorry to imaklaus I can only accept one. ;(

Answer (score 2):

```
df['result'] = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x: ['Y' if i in ' '.join(x['name1'].astype(str)) else 'N' for i in list(x['name2'].dropna().str.split().str[0])]).tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   id type     name1      name2 result
0   1    A  James B.      James      Y
1   2    A     Keras     Steven      N
2   3    A       NaN      Keras      Y
3   4    B      Jack       Lucy      Y
4   5    B      Lucy       Jack      Y
5   6    C    Jasica     Hoverd      N
6   7    C    Steven     Jasica      Y
7   8    C       NaN  Steven L.      Y
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error with my actual data `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`.

Comment: @iamklaus - it match `NaN`s witn `NaNs` - cannot convert both

Comment: @jezrael was skeptical about dropping them, went with casting all to str then doing the split.

Comment: one convert, another remove, check my answer